# How to get the other values that are not in the association table using Entity Framework code first

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

I have a `UserClasses`, `Screens` and `Workflow` tables.  The Workflow table is the association table between the UserClasses and Screens tables.  Here are their structures...

```
UserClasses
- UserClassID (int PK)
- UserClass (string)

Screens
- ScreenID (int PK)
- ScreenName (string)

Workflow
- UserClassificationID
- ScreenID
```

I have the following data in the UserClasses table (Id and name):

```
- 1 UserClassification1
- 2 UserClassification2
- 3 UserClassification3
- 4 UserClassification4
- 5 UserClassification5
```

I have the following data in the Screens table (Id and name):

```
- 1 Screen1
- 2 Screen2
- 3 Screen3
```

I have the following data in the Workflow table (UserClassificationID and ScreenID):

```
1 1
1 2
```

By looking at the data `Screen3` is not associated to a user classification.  This is what I need, a list of all the screens that are not associated to a given user classification.  How would I do this?

Additional information regarding my setup.  The 2 classes that I have defined for the UserClasses and Screens tables:

```
public class UserClassification : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<Screen> Screens { get; set; }
}

public class Screen : IEntity
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<UserClassification> UserClassifications { get; set; }
}
```

Here are the configurations classes that is used in my database context class:

```
class ScreenConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Screen>]
{
     internal ScreenConfiguration()
     {
          this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("ScreenID");
          this.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("ScreenName");
     }
}

class UserClassificationConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserClassification>
{
     internal UserClassificationConfiguration()
     {
          this.ToTable("UserClasses");
          this.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("UserClassID");
          this.Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("UserClass");
          this.HasMany(i => i.Screens)
               .WithMany(c => c.UserClassifications)
               .Map(mc =>
               {
                    mc.MapLeftKey("UserClassificationID");
                    mc.MapRightKey("ScreenID");
                    mc.ToTable("Workflow");
               });
     }
}
```

So given the above information I need to return a user classification object with a list of screens that are not associated to this user classification, in this case that would be a list of 1 screen item.  How would I do something like this?

This is how I return a user classification object with a list of screens that are in the association table:

```
return DbContext.UserClasses
     .Include("Screens")
     .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == userClassificationId);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about ?

```
from s in DbContext.Screens
where s.UserClassifications.Count() == 0
select s
```

hope this helps

Comment: I would like to have a user classification object returned with a list of screens.  Is this possible?

Comment: I think yes : s.UserClassifications.Where(uc => uc.Id == someUserId).Count() == 0.

Comment: Can you maybe have a look at my other similar question as well please?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311272/how-to-handle-an-association-table-linking-the-same-2-tables

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible this way. Eager loading (`Include`) works only with associated objects. You must use projection:

```
var result = DbContext.UserClasses
                      .Where(x => x.Id == userClassificationId)
                      .Select(x => new 
                          {
                              UserClassification = x,
                              Screens = DbContext.Screens
                                                 .Where(s => !s.UserClasses.Any(u => u.Id)
                          })
                      .SingleOrDefault();
```

Now you have anonymous type containing your user classification and all unrelated screens (or null if such user classification doesn't exist). You can build a new user classification object from these informations (it is not possible to do it directly in Linq-to-entities query because EF doesn't allow projecting to mapped type).

Comment: There is an error with your code: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'.  This is where you have u => u.Id

Comment: If possible can you maybe go and look at my similar question as well please?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311272/how-to-handle-an-association-table-linking-the-same-2-tables